# I want to get label of count in bar graph using ggplot

Tags: r

I want to get label of count in bar graph using `ggplot`. I have  tried the following `R` code:

```
ggplot(data = OrgDATA) + 
   geom_bar(aes(y=..count.. , x= as.factor(BUSINESS_UNIT), fill=as.factor(STATUS)),position = position_stack()) + 
   geom_text(aes(label = ..count..),vjust = -0.3) + 
   theme_minimal()
```

Comment: and what happend? Furthermore, please add some reproducible data.

Comment: I am getting the bar graph , but without any label on it while using the code which i uploaded